# How to delete a node from an XML document in Python using ElementTree

Tags: python, elementtree

Here's the structure:

```
   <foo>
        <bar> 
    <buildCommand>
        <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
        <triggers>auto,full,incremental,</triggers>
    </buildCommand>
        </bar>
   </foo>
```

and here's my logic, which identifies the buildCommand I want to delete (the second one), adds it to a list, and then does a remove.

```
import os;
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

document = ET.parse("foo"); 
root = document.getroot(); 
removeList = list()
for child in root.iter('buildCommand'): 
   if (child.tag == 'buildCommand'): 
      name = child.find('name').text
      if (name == 'org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder'):
          removeList.append(child)

for tag in removeList:
   root.remove(tag)

document.write("newfoo")
```

Python 2.7.1 has the remove command but I get an error on remove:

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 337, in remove
    self._children.remove(element)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

UPDATE:

*** Solved by @martijn-pieters - correct logic for second for loop is

```
for tag in removeList:
   parent = root.find('bar')
   parent.remove(tag)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the element from its *parent*; you'll need to get a reference to the parent directly though, there is no path from child back up. In this case you'll have to get a reference to the `<bar>` element at the same time as finding the `<buildCommand>` element.

Trying to remove the tag from the root fails because the tag is not a direct child of the root.

Comment: Thanks!  Updated the question to show your answer.  Is this the most pythonic way to do this kind of "XML editing" or should I use another approach, like building a parallel document and just excluding that node?

Comment: I'd switch to `lxml` instead; it supports the same API but adds better XPath support plus access to the parent of a node.

Comment: I have not gone the lxml route for now because I'm on Mac OSX 10.7, and it doesn't have lxml - here are ideas for folks who want lxml on that platform though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961577/need-help-installing-lxml-on-os-x-10-7

Comment: I'm on Mac and I use `lxml` all the time. :-)